# Trying to create an array within an array dynamically with a GET Request

Tags: ios, arrays, multidimensional-array, swift3

I'm trying to create an array within an array with a GET Request I'm making. I want the data look something like

```
[heroesOfLOTR[Gandalf, Frodo, Aragorn], heroesOfStarWars[Yoda, Luke, ObiWan],heroesOfWheelOfTime[Rand, Matt, Perrin]]
```

I've looked through multiple posts about multi-dimensional arrays, but the data is usually with a set number, and does not work dynamically. I also see a lot of results that look like this:

```
[[1,2,3][1,2,3,4][1,2]]
```

Currently, thats what my data looks like, and can't figure to a solution to get it to work like the first array mentioned.

I've tried at least 10 or 15 combinations of code, but am unable to find a solution.

JSON

```
{ HeroLOTR  heroes:[ {Sam} {Frodo} {Gandalf}], {HeroesOfStarWars  heroes:[ {Yoda} {Luke} {ObiWan}]
```

Comment: For starters, you're going to want to tell your collectionView and tableView to `reloadData()` after you're done receiving an parsing the arrays. Otherwise those views won't ever update to reflect the data you've put in the arrays.

Comment: it's just the name of the array, not the actual tableview or collection view. I'll change the name of clarities sake

Comment: I know, but it looks like you're using the data in those arrays to populate the data in your table view and collection view. Once you're done filling those arrays with data, you need to call `reloadData()` on each respective view or else they'll never show the data you just received.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand where this is failing without more info on what data is received. I'm going to assume you're actually getting the data back. Are you able to parse the data into the CalendarClass objects? Or is it just failing to show the data in the UI?

Comment: So my goal is to put a collectionView within a tableview and access the CalendarArray like CalanderArray = [collectionView.tag][indexPath.item]. But I can't do this if the way I parse and put the data into an array is wrong. My questions that I asked is just trying to figure out how to get array and it's data like [heroesOfLOTR[Gandalf, Frodo, Aragorn], heroesOfStarWars[Yoda, Luke, ObiWan],heroesOfWheelOfTime[Rand, Matt, Perrin]]

Comment: I'm just going to delete my code, I think it confuses the point I'm after.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for this structure [[String:[Int]]]

eg: [ "HeroesOfLOTR":[Gandalf, Frodo] ]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'd recommend here:

First, create a more descriptive class or struct for your heroes. This isn't a requirement but will make your code much more readable and understandable as you continue development.

```
class Hero { // Switch "class" to "struct" if you want a struct
  // Add whatever properties you want here
  let name: String

  init?(json: [String: Any]) {
    guard let name = json["name"] as? String else {
      return nil
    }
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

Second, it appears you're trying to put each of the heroes into an array (a set would work here too). You can again create a class or struct to hold these heroes.

```
class HeroGroup { // Just switch "class" to "struct" if you want a struct  
  let name: String
  let heroes: [Hero]

  init?(json: [String: Any?]) {
    guard let name = json["name"] as? String else {
      return nil
    }
    self.name = name

    self.heroes = (json["heroes"] as? [[String: Any]])?.flatMap { Hero(json: $0) } ?? []
  }
}
```

Lastly, when you receive your response, you can just write code like the following in your completion closure:

```
guard let groups = response.value.arrayValue as? [[String: Any]] else {
  return // Have JSON that you can't parse
}

// This will give you [HeroGroup]
self.groupsOfHeroes = groups.flatMap { HeroGroup(json: $0) } // This is a property on your view controller
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Still wrapping my head around this and implementing it into my code. The example I gave you was just made up because I can't really share my API. Sorry for the confusion and not sharing the entire thing to give you context. So is group of heroes the Array within an array? Do I access it like groupOfHeroes[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item]?

Comment: I'm going to give you an example of what the JSON looks like as well. Or at least, a dummy data version of it.